# Php excel formula not running in saved spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using php excel codeplex, I'm filling a cell like this:

```
$objWorksheet->setCellValue('B12', "='Other sheet'!D38");
```

I save the file successfully, when I open it the formula is there, but it doesn't render the calculated value.
If I copy and paste the formula to another cell it runs ok, so, it's not a problem of the formula's syntax.
How can I force the formula to execute before saving? I have tried:

```
\PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->disableCalculationCache();
\PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->clearCalculationCache();
```

Without success...

Comment: you can force recalcution before saving

Comment: What version of PHPExcel are you running? Automatic calculation on save has recently been disabled in the develop branch code

Comment: To re-enable calculation on save, call the `setPreCalculateFormulas()` method of your Writer before saving.... quick question though, what Writer are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm using dev/master through composer. Aplying setPreCalculateFormulas() on the writer did the trick, do you want to add the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a sample code to solve the problem:

```
$spreadsheet = new \PHPExcel();
$writer = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($spreadsheet);

//Do things with the $spreadsheet

//This is the solution, do it before saving
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(); 
$writer->save($saving_filepath);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

I added this code and it is working for me.

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($excelObj)->disableCalculationCache();
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($excelObj)->clearCalculationCache();
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelObj, 'Excel2007');

$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
$writer->save($output_file);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel), you can easily set up calculation during export in the `excel.php` config file. Just set the option `calculate` to true.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Pre-calculate formulas during export
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
'calculate'                   => true,
```