# it is possible to do PERCENTILE.EXC in laravel? If yes how?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpoffice

I am creating a program that generate report in excel.
And some of my problem is when generating excel I need a formula like Percentile

Percentile link: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-percentile.exc-function

I found a link of T-SQL that generate percentile but I really don't understand it.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/using-the-t-sql-percentile-analytic-functions-in-sql-server-2000-2005-and-2008/

What I need is how can I do in query in laravel that do percentile. can you give me some example or link.

I am currently using laravel 5.2 and phpoffice/phpexcel
Link of phpoffice/phpexcel:
https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302389/how-can-insert-formula-in-excel-sheet-using-phpexcel

Comment: @VijaySankhat thank you for the link Sir but I already try using formula my problem on it is, its not automatic calculating. So I think I should compute it using query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550027/php-excel-formula-not-running-in-saved-spreadsheet

Comment: Need to enable it like this `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);`

Comment: Have you tried previous comment code?